# Show $A \subset S$ (open) is a regular surface if $S \subset \mathbb R^3$ is a regular surface.

Tags: general-topology

Let $S\subset \mathbb R^3$ be a regular surface and let $A \subset S$ be open.

I want to show that $A$ is also a regular surface.

For this I must show that given $x \in A$ there exist an open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ in the subspace topology induced by $A$, an open set $U \in \mathbb R^2$ and a mapping $\sigma: U \rightarrow V$ such that:

$\sigma$ is smooth,

$\sigma$ is a homeomorphism

$q \in U$ implies that the vector $\sigma_u(q), \sigma_v(q)$ are linearly independent.

How can I utilize that $S$ is a regular surface in proving this ? I've been looking at inverse function theorem and tried to relate the open neighbourhoods corresponding to $A$ and $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in A$. Let $\sigma_x:U_x\rightarrow V_x\ni x$  as given by the fact that $S$ is a surface.

Then $\sigma_x|_{\sigma_x^{-1}(V_x\cap A)}:\sigma_x^{-1}(V_x\cap A)\rightarrow V_x\cap A$

- is a smooth function defined from an open subset of $U_x$ onto an open subset of $V_x$ (in the subspace topology).
- is a homeomorphism, because it's the restriction of a homeomorphism
- the third condition is invariant under restriction to open subsets